Draw on Compose canvas by pixels
I have an image encoded as 2D array of colors like this:
val pixels = arrayOf(
  arrayOf(color1, color2,... colorN),
  ...
)

I would like to draw it pixel-by-pixel on Compose Canvas (desktop application, not Android):
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
          .size(200.dp)
          .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        drawPixels(pixels) //need function like this
    }

The only way I found is to use drawPoints but it required list of points for every color. Not the best way if I have hundreds of different colors.
How can I draw an array of pixels?

Your array is effectively a bitmap, a list of colors for each pixel. Bitmaps can be drawn into a Canvas with drawImage.
The only thing to do is to convert your array of arrays into the proper bitmap format:
fun ImageBitmap(colors: Array<Array<Color>>): ImageBitmap {
    val bytesPerPixel = 4 // Alpha, Red, Green, Blue

    val width = colors.firstOrNull()?.size ?: 0
    val height = colors.size

    val bytes = ByteArray(width * height * bytesPerPixel)
    colors.forEachIndexed { x, row ->
        row.forEachIndexed { y, color ->
            with(color.convert(ColorSpaces.Srgb).value) {
                repeat(bytesPerPixel) {
                    bytes[x * width * bytesPerPixel + y * bytesPerPixel + it] =
                        shr(32 + it * 8).toByte()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val image: Image = Image.makeRaster(
        imageInfo = ImageInfo.makeN32Premul(width, height),
        bytes = bytes,
        rowBytes = width * 4,
    )

    return image.toComposeImageBitmap()
}

This assumes your array contains colors of type androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.
You can now simply draw this bitmap into the Canvas:
val image = remember(pixels) { ImageBitmap(pixels) }

Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(200.dp)
        .background(Color.White)
) {
    drawImage(image)
}


On Android this would be a lot easier because we can create a android.graphics.Bitmap:
import android.graphics.Bitmap

fun <T> createBitmap(
    colors: Array<Array<T>>,
    transform: (T) -> Int,
    config: Bitmap.Config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,
): Bitmap {
    val intColors = colors
        .flatten()
        .map(transform)
        .toIntArray()
    val width = colors.firstOrNull()?.size ?: 0
    val height = colors.size

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(
        intColors,
        width,
        height,
        config,
    )
}

It can also use other color types as input. For an array of androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Colors the bitmap would be created like this:
val bitmap = createBitmap(pixels, Color::toArgb)

The config parameter is used to specify the type of the bitmap. The default is ARGB_8888 (simple 8 bit sRGB values with alpha) which should be a good fit for a Canvas.
You can now simply draw this bitmap into the Canvas:
Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(200.dp)
        .background(Color.White)
) {
    drawImage(
        image = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
    )
}

If you call createBitmap from a composable make sure you remember the result so it isn't recreated on every recomposition.

Thank you @Leviathan! Yes, this is definatly what I was looking for.
